# Set relative positioned image tag to take up 100% of parent div's vertical space

Tags: css

I have an image `div` that I previously had positioned perfectly by using an absolute positioned image in a relative positioned parent `div` as is often suggested. I'm in the process of animating that image, and it needs to be relative positioned without a container `div` in order to animate properly with the method I'm using (GSAP/Motion Path).

I temporarily set the height of my logo to 10vh, since setting height to 100% causes it to take up most of the screen. I also tried setting logo to `object-fit: cover` and `contain`, but neither has any effect even if I set width and height to 100%.

Here's what it looks like. I'm trying to center the image with a grey background and have it fill the vertical space of the red `div`.

[image]

Here's my CodePen.

https://codepen.io/TheNomadicAspie/pen/YzVLaMr

And here's my code:

```js
logo.src = "https://i.imgur.com/D9LOkQI.png";
menu_image.src = "https://i.imgur.com/l6GysYf.png";
```

```css
* {
  outline: none;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -mo-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  font-size: 2vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: open_sans;
}

.screen {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
}

.menu-bar {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 33.33% 33.33% 33.33%;
  position: relative;
  height: 13.714%;
  width: 100vw;
  top: 0%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: red;
}

.logo {
  grid-column: 1/2;
  position: relative;
  height: 10vh;
  background-color: grey;
}

.title {
  grid-column: 2/3;
  position: relative;
  color: #f5f5f5;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: hack;
  font-size: clamp(2vw, 8vw, 10vh);
  display: flex;
  top: 0%;
}

.menu-button {
  grid-column: 3/4;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

.menu-button img {
  position: absolute;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 75%;
  max-width: 75%;
  left: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  bottom: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.display {
  position: relative;
  height: 86.286%;
  width: 100vw;
}

.speech-bubble {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 80% 0% 20%;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  height: 61.8%;
  width: 90vw;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 2em;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div id="screen" class="screen">
  <div id="menu_bar" class="menu-bar">
    <img id="logo" class="logo">
    <div id="title" class="title">Title</div>
    <div id="menu_button" class="menu-button"> <img id="menu_image"> </div>
  </div>
  <div id="display" class="display">
    <div id="speech_bubble" class="speech-bubble">
      <div id="logo_animation" class="logo-animation" data-flip-id="logo">
        <img id="logo_animation_image">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I set width to auto and height to 100% and it works.

[image: Screenshot_cropped]

```js
logo.src = "https://i.imgur.com/D9LOkQI.png";
menu_image.src = "https://i.imgur.com/l6GysYf.png";
```

```css
* {
  outline: none;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -mo-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  font-size: 2vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: open_sans;
}

.screen {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
}

.menu-bar {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 33.33% 33.33% 33.33%;
  position: relative;
  height: 13.714%;
  width: 100vw;
  top: 0%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: red;
}

.logo {
  grid-column: 1/2;
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background-color: grey;
}

.title {
  grid-column: 2/3;
  position: relative;
  color: #f5f5f5;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: hack;
  font-size: clamp(2vw, 8vw, 10vh);
  display: flex;
  top: 0%;
}

.menu-button {
  grid-column: 3/4;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

.menu-button img {
  position: absolute;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 75%;
  max-width: 75%;
  left: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  bottom: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.display {
  position: relative;
  height: 86.286%;
  width: 100vw;
}

.speech-bubble {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 80% 0% 20%;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  height: 61.8%;
  width: 90vw;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 2em;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
}
```

```html
    <div id="screen" class="screen">
        <div id="menu_bar" class="menu-bar">
            <img id="logo" class="logo">
            <div id="title" class="title">Title</div>
            <div id="menu_button" class="menu-button"> <img id="menu_image"> </div>
        </div>
        <div id="display" class="display">
            <div id="speech_bubble" class="speech-bubble">
                <div id="logo_animation" class="logo-animation" data-flip-id="logo">
                    <img id="logo_animation_image">
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Logo takes up the entire screen in your code snippet as well as mine. I need it to only take up the vertical space of the red div.

Comment: I added a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this. I changed a little bit of CSS for logo class.
Hope it will help you out but if you want perfectly aligned navbar I recommend you to use flexbox.

```js
logo.src = "https://i.imgur.com/D9LOkQI.png";
menu_image.src = "https://i.imgur.com/l6GysYf.png";
```

```css
* {
  outline: none;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -mo-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  font-size: 2vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: open_sans;
}

.screen {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
}

.menu-bar {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 33.33% 33.33% 33.33%;
  position: relative;
  height: 13.714%;
  width: 100vw;
  top: 0%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: red;
}

.logo {
  grid-column: 1/2;
  height: 13.714vh;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: grey;
  left:50%;
  top:0px;
}

.title {
  grid-column: 2/3;
  position: relative;
  color: #f5f5f5;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: hack;
  font-size: clamp(2vw, 8vw, 10vh);
  display: flex;
  top: 0%;
}

.menu-button {
  grid-column: 3/4;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

.menu-button img {
  position: absolute;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 75%;
  max-width: 75%;
  left: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  bottom: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.display {
  position: relative;
  height: 86.286%;
  width: 100vw;
}

.speech-bubble {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 80% 0% 20%;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  height: 61.8%;
  width: 90vw;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 2em;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
}
```

```html
    <div id="screen" class="screen">
        <div id="menu_bar" class="menu-bar">
            <img id="logo" class="logo">
            <div id="title" class="title">Title</div>
            <div id="menu_button" class="menu-button"> <img id="menu_image"> </div>
        </div>
        <div id="display" class="display">
            <div id="speech_bubble" class="speech-bubble">
                <div id="logo_animation" class="logo-animation" data-flip-id="logo">
                    <img id="logo_animation_image">
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but as I said I can't use absolute positioning for the logo dev. The admin of GSAP told using absolute positioning can cause some issues with the animation I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

i just put image in a div and centered vertically with `top:50%;transform: translateY(-50%)`.

Update:
then center both directions with translate()

```js
logo.src = "https://i.imgur.com/D9LOkQI.png";
menu_image.src = "https://i.imgur.com/l6GysYf.png";
```

```css
* {
  outline: none;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -mo-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  font-size: 2vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: open_sans;
}

.screen {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
}

.menu-bar {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 33.33% 33.33% 33.33%;
  position: relative;
  height: 13.714%;
  width: 100vw;
  top: 0%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: red;
}

.logo {
  grid-column: 1/2;
  position: relative;
  height: 10vh;
  background-color: grey;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}

.title {
  grid-column: 2/3;
  position: relative;
  color: #f5f5f5;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: hack;
  font-size: clamp(2vw, 8vw, 10vh);
  display: flex;
  top: 0%;
}

.menu-button {
  grid-column: 3/4;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

.menu-button img {
  position: absolute;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 75%;
  max-width: 75%;
  left: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  bottom: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.display {
  position: relative;
  height: 86.286%;
  width: 100vw;
}

.speech-bubble {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 80% 0% 20%;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  height: 61.8%;
  width: 90vw;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 2em;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div id="screen" class="screen">
  <div id="menu_bar" class="menu-bar">
    <img id="logo" class="logo">
    <div id="title" class="title">Title</div>
    <div id="menu_button" class="menu-button"> <img id="menu_image"> </div>
  </div>
  <div id="display" class="display">
    <div id="speech_bubble" class="speech-bubble">
      <div id="logo_animation" class="logo-animation" data-flip-id="logo">
        <img id="logo_animation_image">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: As I said in my post, I was specifically advised NOT to put it in a container div by the dev of GSAP, the animation library I'm using. It was in a container div originally, and because of the way I'm animating if I need to have the image relatively positioned with no container div. Is there no way of doing that?

Comment: sorry didn't see because of the rush.. I updated the code. I centered it with `translate(-50%,-50%)`, so idk will there be a problem..

Comment: I appreciate it, but as you said the translate property does prevent the animation from working. I guess I'll just have to find another method. Thank you .